# Duplicate rows in bulk in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, duplicates

[image]
How can I duplicate a single cell in column 'A' into 8 rows without having to do it manually? I've searched through various sources and asked AI, but the problem hasn't been solved yet. I hope the experts can help me.

I have tried to search through numerous sources and asked AI, but still couldn't succeed. I spent a whole day searching but still couldn't achieve the expected results.

Comment: Google sheets or excel?

Comment: @TheMaster Would `=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(IF(SEQUENCE(1,8),A1:A17)))` be an improvement on your answer to the duplicate question?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yup. Nice catch...I thought the vertical range length of `IF` should be equal to the resulting range. But that doesn't need to be the case, if it's just a 1D range in another axis. If you'd like to edit my answer directly, do so. Or add another answer as you wish.

Comment: @TheMaster IMO, this way of repeating vectors has since become common knowledge (see e.g. Jos Woolley's answer below and probably a few other answers) so I suggest you edit your answer so people can utilize the improved version. Don't even credit me since I actually never use Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

For Excel:

```
=LET(φ,8,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,φ),A1:A17)))
```

Amend the 8 and range as required.

Comment: it not working "#NAME?"

Comment: So what have you checked for this error? maybe your Excel version?

Comment: Is there a reason in using `LET` here? `φ` is used just once in the answer.

Comment: @TheMaster I sometimes also use `LET` to bring any key variables to the very beginning of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$13;INT(ROW(C1)/8)+1;1)
```

change A$13 to the end of data in column A. Type in cell C1 and copy down.

Comment: it error : https://prnt.sc/aspUL82ShDPB

Comment: So did you check if your system uses the comma as the separator or the semi-colon ;

Comment: @Thành Khải Change ; (semi-colon) to , (comma) as Solar Mike commented. The separator depends on local settings (decimal point)